# I'm having trouble with tic tac toe?

Tags: c++

How do I not allow the user to enter the same move twice? For example player X enters 1 then player O enters one or X enters 1 again the next turn. How do make them reenter a valid input?
[My code](http://cpp.sh/54s2k)

Comment: Homework? Boil down your code to something that encapsulates your problem. You posted an entire program.

Comment: Use a `do {} while(..);` loop until they have entered a valid move.

Comment: You can use a `if(){} else{}` loop to check whether in that box a move have been played or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use a data structure (such as an array or vector) to store the moves that have already been made. If a user tries to enter a move that has already been made, re-prompt them:

```
void getMove()
{
//Get move input from user through something like std::cin
    if (hasBeenPlayed()) //If the move (ex: 1) is already in the array or vector
    {
    getMove();
    }
    else
    {
    playedMoves.push_back(move); // Add the move to the vector (or an array)
    //Compute the move that was entered here
    }
}
```